# Active Content-Security-Policy (CSP) and Rails :back link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, content-security-policy

I want to allow the internal Rails :back link functionality for my application with an active Content-Security-Policy.

CSP:

```
%meta{"http-equiv" => "Content-Security-Policy", "content" => "default-src *;"}
```

Example link:

```
= link_to 'Back', :back
# <a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a> *
```

> * Rails links to the referer and only if no referer is set falls back to JS.

How can I whitelist only this tiny `history.back()` piece of javascript?

I tried to set an exception as described in https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage and generated the required hash like this:

```
echo -n "history.back()" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Result:

```
%meta{"http-equiv" => "Content-Security-Policy", "content" => "default-src *; script-src 'self' 'sha256-LdlORHyUW/rwezK0l13nW+IwcZmi78eWOCBjewMWRr4='"}
```

But the Chrome console displays the same error what means the hash is invalid:

> Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'sha256-SmahML3R6+R4SRnsB6tEJ8Z4OVa4Qhk7A/gv3eAiG6s='". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash-whitelisting inline code oder inline styles is not possible with an active Content Security Policy. The above example would only work if `history.back()` was the content of a script-tag like this:

```
<script>history.back()</script>
```

Chrome's error message is misleading, because it suggests using the hash method for whitelisting the inline code which is actually not supported.

The same applies for inline styles like `style="display:none"` (used for example in nested_form gem).

The use of `unsafe-inline` was no option for my project. So I solved these rare problems by monkey patching the class or module to use different markup (for example `class="hidden"`) plus some additional external javascript where required but of course there are drawbacks when updating the affected gems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also move the JS to an external file on your server and include it with `<script src=...>`. Your CSP allows *, so also your own origin ('self'). Then use unobtrusive JavaScript to react to a click on the link. Here's the idea: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately this won't solve my problem because the html code and javascript for the back link is generated by Rails and not by me.

Comment: Indeed. What I'd suggest is not using link_to 'Back', :back, but something like link_to 'Back', '#', data: {behavior: 'back-link'}. Then in JS: $('[data-behavior~=back-link]').on('click', function(){history.back});